# Открытие проекта в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

В при работе с Visual Studio можно запустить файл проекта с расширением .sln и тогда проект полностью откроется в среде разработки. Файл с каким расширением необходимо запустить в Android Studio, чтобы открыть весь проект?

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы открыть проект кликом по файлу, запускайте файл с расширенением .iml в корне проекта. Имя файла совпадает с именем проекта.

Например для проекта Sample запускаете файл *sample.iml* в корне папок проекта Sample

Answer (score 0):

вам нужен файл с папки app - build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Если вы сделали свой первый проект и не можете его открыть в студии:

1. Запуск проекта: app\build.gradle
2. Находим и указываем приложение которым открыть файл.
3. Указываем путь к sdk он может лежать тут: C:\Users{your_user}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
4. Если sdk не найдено, создайте новый проект, при старте откроется sdk menedger
5. Укажите нормальную папку для хранения sdk т.к. геморой с открытием проектов будет повторяться.